# Why does an induction generator operate at leading power factor?

Tags: power-electronics, generator, induction-motor

The power factor of a single-phase induction motor is usually lagging whereas the power factor of an induction generator is leading.

From my understanding an induction motor needs reactive power to setup the magnetic field, hence it draws more reactive power (magnetizing component of current is greater than reactive component) from the supply than active power.

How can we say that an induction generator operates with a leading power factor and is more suitable for supplying resistive loads?